# How send one message to all lissener queue?

Tags: node.js, queue, rabbitmq, amqp

I use rabbitMq, nodeJs(with socet.io, amqp modules), ZF2 for development chat

By default RabbitMq send message from queue at help Round-robin.

**Does RabbitMq opportunity to send all subscriber queue the same message?**

For example:
If i make for each connection its queue, that is work correct, but if user open 2 tabs on him browser, then will make 2 queue. I think its not good.

I want have one queue for each users(if i make that, than first message send to first tab, second message - to second tab)

My code:

```
 var exchange = connectionAmqp.exchange('chat', {type: 'direct', passive: false, durable:false, autoDelete: false});


                    console.log(' [*] Client connected')

                    connectionAmqp.queue('chat'+userId.toString(), {
                        passive : false,
                        durable : false,
                        exclusive : false,
                        autoDelete: false
                    }, function(queue) {

                        //Catch new message from queue
                        queue.bind(exchange, userId.toString());
                        queue.subscribe(function(msg){                           
                             socket.emit('pullMessage', msg); //Emit message to browser         
                        })

                    });
```

From other script i push message

```
var exchange = connectionAmqp.exchange('chat', {type: 'direct', passive: false, durable:false, autoDelete: false});
var data= {chatId:70,msg:"Text",time:1375333200}
exchange.publish('1', data, {contentType: 'application/json'});
```

Comment: looking at the two answers it seems a little unclear as to what you are actually trying to achieve.  Why do you want a round robin for chat clients, presumably you want a topic where all clients for the same user will get all messages, but not all clients get all messages

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the queues are not exclusive.  Then make sure the client connects to the same queue.  This can be done but having the client create the queue and specifying the name of that queue.  The naming algorithm will make sure that the queue name is unique per client, but for the same client it will produce the same name.  Both tabs will read in turn from the same queue ensuring the round robin effect that you are looking for.

Comment: Yes, I and do. Its not work for me
I add my code to main question

Comment: The naming algorithm does not produce the same name for a client. Each anonymous queue will have its own name.

Comment: the OP is not creating anonymous queues

Comment: That's true. I thought you meant the server's naming. However, I believe he is not interested in having round-robin consumption, but wants every message on every tab.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to send a message to all queues, you can use an exchange of type **fanout**. See [here](http://www.rabbitmq.com/img/tutorials/intro/exchange-fanout.png)! It will broadcast a message to each queue bound to it. However, if you are attaching two consumers (callbacks) on one queue, those two consumers (callbacks) will still be fed round-robin wise.

Queues are very lightweight and RabbitMQ is build to handle many queues, so it's ok to create a queue for each tab. If you are still unsure, this [post](http://videlalvaro.github.io/2011/05/rabbitmq-chat-post-mortem.html) may be of your interest. The author build a simple chat system and stress tested it, showing that RabbitMQ easily handles thousands of queues and messages per second.

Although it is possible to do this with just one queue per user, it will be far easier with one queue per tab...and when using RabbitMQ there is usually no need to do such optimizations*.

*(of course there are exceptions)

Comment: Fan out doesn't work here, because you do not want all clients getting all messages.  you need a topic or direct exchange where a routing key is specified to make sure only specific clients get messages directed at them

Comment: If this is the case, I don't understand at all, what the OP is trying to do.

Comment: I am not clear either.  However fanout cannot be correct as separate clients need to get different messages

Comment: I thought of chatrooms, where every user sees every message. Might be creation of a exclusive fanout exchange for each user suitable? I am not sure how expensive exchanges are in comparison to queues.